# How to install Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-installation, 21.04, iwlwifi

I just bought new laptop MSI Bravo 15 b5dd-042ru. I installed Ubuntu 21.04 on it near windows 10. But it is some problem: no WiFi in setting. Only cable.

I inputted this:

```
sudo lspci | grep Network
```

And got this:

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
```

So, I want to install this driver: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

But instruction is not full and understandable.

UPD:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Returns empty.

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Returns:

```
[    3.040144] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.051131] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.051154] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    3.051474] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.131919] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    3.364842] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: base HW address: f0:9e:4a:a3:d8:dd
[    3.382940] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
```

UPD2:

```
sudo dmesg | grep wlp
```

Returns:

```
[sudo] пароль для andrey: 
[    3.382940] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.832869] wlp5s0: authenticate with c8:be:19:7d:6d:7e
[    8.848981] wlp5s0: send auth to c8:be:19:7d:6d:7e (try 1/3)
[    8.904053] wlp5s0: authenticated
[    8.905926] wlp5s0: associate with c8:be:19:7d:6d:7e (try 1/3)
[    8.910222] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from c8:be:19:7d:6d:7e (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[    8.938440] wlp5s0: associated
[    8.996530] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
```

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

Returns:

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID              MODE            CHAN  RATE      SI>
*       C8:BE:19:7D:6D:7E  DSL_2640NRU       Инфраструктура  6     65 МБ/с   85>
        D8:47:32:AE:18:AD  TP-Link_18AD      Инфраструктура  3     130 МБ/с  84>
        D8:47:32:AE:18:AC  TP-Link_18AD_5G   Инфраструктура  48    270 МБ/с  55>
        80:26:89:12:81:B9  MTSRouter-1281B9  Инфраструктура  13    130 МБ/с  52>
        A4:2B:B0:E7:13:A5  CAPITAL           Инфраструктура  12    270 МБ/с  37>
        BC:F6:85:3F:1D:BC  Room105           Инфраструктура  11    130 МБ/с  32>
lines 1-7/7 (END)
```

Comment: Let's see if the firmware, which is what is referred to in the link you gave, is the real problem. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 , I added

Comment: Normal so far! Now let's see: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp` and: `nmcli device wifi list` We don't need to see the whole list; just does it see your router or is there an error.

Comment: @chili555 , Yes, it see

Comment: Your wireless is working normally and is connected. Is the only problem that you don't see the Network Manager icon at the top right, like this? https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2014/07/ubuntu-networkmanager-menu-100360176-large.png?auto=webp

Comment: Please also show: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`